# 'float' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'", 'occurred at index 30852'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timezone-offset

I was trying to localize the timezone for the dataset using this code:

```py
df['Date and Time'] = df['Date and Time'].astype('datetime64')
df['Date and Time'] = df.apply(lambda r : r['Date and Time (RW)'].tz_localize(r['Zone']), 1)
```

However, I keep on getting error message which said:

> "'float' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'", 'occurred at index 30852"

When I tried to see which data is causing the error:

```py
df[(df.index==30852)] # actually it shows that there is no data.
```

I tried to drop the data at that index by running this code:

```py
df.drop(df.index[30852], inplace=True)
```

but it didn't work because there's no data.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: could you share some sample data?

Comment: shouldn't something like: `df['result'] = df['Date and Time (RW)'].astype('datetime64').tz_localize(df['Zone']` work? I'm just guessing here since I couldn't try it myself

Comment: @politicalscientist Never mind. The problem had to do with when I had to merge two tables together. I had NA values and it resulted in the error. Thanks!